# how to convert a Vec<&str> to Vec<usize>

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust programming language. I was trying to covert  Vec<&str> to Vec
but I get the below error. I don't know the reason for that. is anyone there to help me understand why this happens.

My code:

```
let result: Vec<usize> = "123456789"    
          .split("") 
          .map(|x| x.parse::<usize>().unwrap())  
          .collect();
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: Empty }', src/main.rs:92:37
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: `.split(' ')` ?

Comment: <https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split>: ‘When the empty string is used as a separator, it separates every character in the string, along with the beginning and end of the string.’. Look at the example below that.

Comment: I clearly mentioned in the question that I want to convert Vec<&str> to Vec<usize> 

["1" ,"2" ] => [1,2]

Comment: You say you want to convert `Vec<&str>` to `Vec<usize>`, but you don't actually start out with `Vec<&str>`, but with a single `&str`. Maybe you meant something like `vec!["123", "456"].iter().map(|s| s.parse::<usize>().unwrap()).collect()`?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split:

> When the empty string is used as a separator, it separates every character in the string, along with the beginning and end of the string.

```
let f: Vec<_> = "rust".split("").collect();
assert_eq!(f, &["", "r", "u", "s", "t", ""]);
```

So your split does not do what you think it does, as it prepends and appends an empty string, which fail to be parsed as an integer.

There are a few different ways to do what you want here, for example, you can just ignore the invalid conversions by using flat_map:

```
let result: Vec<usize> = "123456789"    
          .split("")
          .flat_map(|x| x.parse::<usize>())  
          .collect();
```

You can also not use split, but iterate on `chars` instead, and use the `char::to_digit` method:

```
let result: Vec<usize> = "123456789"    
          .chars()
          .flat_map(|c| c.to_digit(10))
          .map(|n| n as usize)
          .collect();
```

Note that these examples avoid using `unwrap` so these will never panic, even if the input string is invalid.

An approach that allows you to get an error in case of problem could be the following:

```
let result: Result<Vec<usize>, String> = "123456789"
    .chars()
    .map(|c| {
        c.to_digit(10)
            .map(|n| n as usize)
            .ok_or(format!("invalid digit: {c}"))
    })
    .collect();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are getting things that you cannot parse. Check this example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let result: Vec<_> = "123456789"
        .split("")
        .collect();
    println!("{result:?}");
}
```

which outputs:

`["", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ""]`

You can filter those empty strings (`""`) first for solving your problem:

```rust
let result: Vec<usize> = "123456789"    
          .split("")
          .filter(|x| !x.is_empty())
          .map(|x| x.parse::<usize>().unwrap())  
          .collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2faf152cef7c84730cb53928f595faf6)

You can also use the `str::chars` method, and then the [`char::to_digit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_digit):

```rust
fn main() {
    let result: Vec<usize> = "123456789"
        .chars()
        .map(|x| x.to_digit(10).unwrap() as usize)
        .collect();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=945b00f453b2c66dc369e5936fea674a)